# Bootstrap mobile dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to get the mobile dropdown working on this navbar, I have all the files required but still it wont allow any items to drop down (in mobile view?)

Is there something I am missing that I cannot see

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="background-color: lightgrey;">Site</a>
    </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Site</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Rules</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Results</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Request Account</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Site</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    @include('layouts.header')

    @include('layouts.footer')

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) Make sure you're loading jQuery *before* loading Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you create a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/)?

Comment: _jQuery_ needs to come **before** _Bootstrap.js_ and `data-target="navbar-main"` should be `data-target="#navbar-main"` (add #).

Comment: Ah Thank you ! I put jQ before Bootstrap and it works now!

Comment: @vanburen please make that an answer so the OP can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the `#` in your `data-target` value.  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNVOYZ?editors=1000)

```
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
```